# Flatmap a Java list in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a Java interface, with a simplified definition

```
public interface JavaInterface {
  List<? extends Foo> getFoos()
}

public interface Foo {
  List<? extends Bar> getBars()
}

public interface Bar { }
```

In scala, I am trying to `flatMap` the lists, and getting errors about `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer` does not match with `scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce`.  It appears that `Buffer` does extend `GenTraversableOnce`, so I think the problem is related to getting the generic parameters to align.

I can get the same compilation error with this Scala code:

```
import java.util._
import java.util.{List => JList}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

trait Base {
    def anotherList: JList[_ <: Base]
}

trait Derived extends Base {}


class Sample
{
    def aList: JList[_ <: Base] = new ArrayList[Base]()

    val foo = aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala)
}
```

which fails as

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/test/scala/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/test/scala/src/main/scala/Test.scala:16:25: no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: _$2 => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_$2],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (_$2 => scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: Base])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : _$2 => scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: Base] where type _$2 <: Base
[error]  required: _$2 => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B] where type _$2 <: Base
[error] val foo = aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala)
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/test/scala/src/main/scala/Test.scala:16:47: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : _$2 => scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_ <: Base] where type _$2 <: Base
[error]  required: _$2 => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B] where type _$2 <: Base
[error] val foo = aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala)
[error]                                               ^
[error] /Users/test/scala/src/main/scala/Test.scala:16:32: Cannot construct a collection of type That with elements of type B based on a collection of type scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[_$2].
[error] val foo = aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala)
[error]                                ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 28, 2019, 5:11:29 PM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this was considered a bug in Scala, not your code, since your code compiles fine in 2.13.  It appears to be an effect of the difference between how variance is handled in Scala `Buffers` versus Java `Lists`.  I think the easiest way to fix it is to use a covariant collection like a Scala `List` inside the `flatMap`, like:

```
aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala.toList)
```

You can also make the type parameter invariant, like:

```
aList.asScala.flatMap(_.anotherList.asScala.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Base]])
```

or

```
aList.asScala.map(_.anotherList.asScala).flatten[Base]
```